# How to call a python script from bash with arguments?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am going round and round in circles here and there is probably a very simple answer.
I have a bash script that loops around video files in a thumbdrive and if it finds the `.mp4` extension, it will upload to youtube using Youtube's python example - which works from the command line.

I'm having trouble passing the arguments to the python script call in the bash script:

```
cd /home/pi/Documents
echo $PWD
for _file in  /media/pi/*/*.mp4; do
     clean=$(echo $_file|wc -m)
     if [ $clean -gt 15 ]; then
           did=$(grep "$_file" /home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt | wc -l)
          if [ $did = 0 ]; then
               #Edit this to your liking
               #echo "now uploading $_file"
               args="--file=\"${_file}\" –-title=\"${_file}\" –-description=\"show 2018\" -–keywords=\"2018,show, Winter,show 2018,\" -–category=\"28\" -–privacyStatus=\"private\""
               python yt_up.py  "$args"
              echo $_file uploaded to youtube via google developer api | logger
               echo $_file >> /home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt
         fi
     fi
done
```

But the arguments are not recognised by the `yt_up.py` script. I've tried various combinations of quotes but I just can't get it to work.

I can pass one argument to the script:

`python yt_up.py --file="$_file"`  works, 
but adding additional arguments were not recognised.

Comment: if you call a python script that does a  `import sys` and `print str(sys.argv)`, what does the output look like?

Comment: Where did you get `yt_up.py` from?

Comment: You are having a typo : `args="--file=\"${_file}\" –-title=\"${_file}\" –-description=\"show 2018\" -–keywords=\"2018,show, Winter,show 2018,\" -–category=\"28\" -–privacyStatus=\"private\""` Watch out `--file=\"${_file}\" –-title=` there is an `–-`instead of `--`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have just to add you argument at in same line as python command. like this

```
python yt_up.py --file="${_file}" –-title="${_file}" --description="show 2018" --keywords="2018,show, Winter,show 2018," -–category="28" --privacyStatus="private"
```

It works

Comment: Thanks, I think it was an accumulation of my typo -- this now works.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of antipatterns and misconceptions in your current code!

```
cd /home/pi/Documents
```

For best practice you should test whether this succeeded. Probably not a problem currently, but it doesn't hurt to do so.

```
echo $PWD
```

Missing quotes here, but that's not fatal.

```
for _file in  /media/pi/*/*.mp4; do
     clean=$(echo $_file|wc -m)
```

That's not how to count the number of characters in a string. You should use `clean=${#_file}` instead.

```
     if [ $clean -gt 15 ]; then
```

Here I guess you want to know whether the glob matched anything. That's not how to proceed. You either want to use the `shopt -s nullglob` option of Bash, or use `if [ -e "$_file" ]; then` to check whether the glob matched an actual file.

```
           did=$(grep "$_file" /home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt | wc -l)
          if [ $did = 0 ]; then
```

That's how you check whether a file doesn't contains a string. Use `if ! grep -q "$_file" /home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt; then` instead.

```
               #Edit this to your liking
               #echo "now uploading $_file"
               args="--file=\"${_file}\" –-title=\"${_file}\" –-description=\"show 2018\" -–keywords=\"2018,show, Winter,show 2018,\" -–category=\"28\" -–privacyStatus=\"private\""
```

Here you have misconceptions about how the shell reads a command. Quote removal is performed before variable expansion, so your quotes are wrong. Typically you want to use an array! that's what Bash arrays are for! Also note that you have some weird hyphens here.

```
               python yt_up.py  "$args"
              echo $_file uploaded to youtube via google developer api | logger
               echo $_file >> /home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt
         fi
     fi
done
```

Here's a possibility to fix your mistakes (and hopefully make it work):

```
#!/bin/bash

# We define a variable with the path to the uploaded_videos.txt file
uploaded_videos=/home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt

# Will expand non-matching globs to nothing:
shopt -s nullglob

# cd into the directory, and exit if fails
cd /home/pi/Documents || exit

# Use the builtin pwd instead of echo "$PWD"
pwd

for file in /media/pi/*/*.mp4; do
    if ! grep -qFx "$file" "$uploaded_videos"; then
        # Define an array to contain the arguments to pass
        args=(
            --file="$file"
            --title="$file"
            --description="show 2018"
            --keywords="2018,show, Winter,show 2018,"
            --category="28"
            --privacyStatus="private"
            )
        # call your script with the fields of the array as arguments
        python yt_up.py "${args[@]}"
        echo "$file uploaded to youtube via google developer api" | logger
        echo "$file" >> "$uploaded_videos"
    fi
done
```

You could improve the final step by explicitly checking whether `yt_up.py` succeeded:

```
if python yt_up.py "${args[@]}"; then
    echo "$file uploaded to youtube via google developer api" | logger
    echo "$file" >> "$uploaded_videos"
else
    echo "Something wrong happened!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `args` variable for python is a large `sys.argv[1]`, so may be you have troubles because of it.

Rewrite shell like this:

```
cd /home/pi/Documents
echo $PWD
for _file in  /media/pi/*/*.mp4; do
     clean=$(echo $_file|wc -m)
     if [ $clean -gt 15 ]; then
          did=$(grep "$_file" /home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt | wc -l)
          if [ $did = 0 ]; then
               #Edit this to your liking
               #echo "now uploading $_file"
               args=( $(echo "--file=\"${_file}\" –-title=\"${_file}\" –-description=\"show 2018\" -–keywords=\"2018,show, Winter,show 2018,\" -–category=\"28\" -–privacyStatus=\"private\"") )
               python yt_up.py  "${args[@]}"
               echo $_file uploaded to youtube via google developer api | logger
               echo $_file >> /home/pi/Documents/uploaded_videos.txt
          fi
     fi
done
```

Now `args` is array, and each it's element will be read by python as separated `sys.argv[i]` element.

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite, however there seems to be an error:
    ./batch2.sh: 10: ./batch2.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Comment: @Nowski have no way to check my code right now, but as I can see it's the same as gniourf_gniourf written above. Try his code, it's best solution. (the longest bash-script)